# can't do yum update on centos6

Tags: centos, centos6

i can't execute yum update or install commands in centos 6 . i got this error
[image]

then i configured my Centos-Base.repo file here's what's in it

```
# CentOS-Base.repo
#
# The mirror system uses the connecting IP address of the client and the
# update status of each mirror to pick mirrors that are updated to and
# geographically close to the client.  You should use this for CentOS updates
# unless you are manually picking other mirrors.
#
# If the mirrorlist= does not work for you, as a fall back you can try the
# remarked out baseurl= line instead.
#
#

[base]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Base
#mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=os&infra=$infra
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/6.10/centosplus/$basearch/
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
gpgcheck=1

#released updates
[updates]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Base
#mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=os&infra=$infra
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/6.10/centosplus/$basearch/
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
gpgcheck=1

#additional packages that may be useful
[extras]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Base
#mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=os&infra=$infra
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/6.10/centosplus/$basearch/
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
gpgcheck=1

#additional packages that extend functionality of existing packages
[centosplus]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Plus
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=centosplus&infra=$infra
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/centosplus/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=0
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6

#contrib - packages by Centos Users
[contrib]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Base
#mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=os&infra=$infra
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/6.10/centosplus/$basearch/
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
gpgcheck=1
```

after saving when , i did yum update again and now a new error appears
[image]

Comment: Please check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72430585/cant-do-yum-update-on-centos6

Answer (score 0):

CentOs 6 is dead and no more supported. Vault repositories are there for those who still need it. In your /etc/yum.repos.d/ folder you should disable the standard CentOs repositories (CentOs-Base, CentOs-fasttrack etc.) and enable just the CentOs-Vault repository. i.e. set enabled=1 for your current release (C6.10 is the last one)